# how do i link my windows form with .NET framework to steam without build errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, visual-studio

It says I have two build errors which I do not know how to fix for some reason. Please help me as I am trying to build a desktop control center for myself. It is also not linking the steam button to steam(yes, I did put steam.exe and the file path, but I get errors still.). The photo below is a photo of my code and what the application looks like.[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vldf7.jpg) [and what the actual application looks like!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxhqa.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace my_app
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control && e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.O)
            {
                // Your code when shortcut Ctrl+Shft+O is pressed
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.netflix.com");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("spotify.exe");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("discord:display");
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("discord.exe");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://github.com/Apexofacircle/TheApexOfAAgent");
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("steam.exe");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `steam.exe` available on the PATH environment variable? Do you get an exception on the `Process.Start()` line?

Comment: Whatchu mean @gunr2171 ?(in simpler terms plz)

Comment: wen u opn command prompt and type "where steam.exe" does u get a path or a not found msg? imma gues u get the msg. You can learn more about PATH from https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them In addition, when you say "but I get errors still", it helps to _actually_ state what those errors are.

Comment: @NotAgent48 I gave you a simple demo using a `docx` file, first you need a full address to run it. If you have any special needs to use `steam.exe` directly, please give your `error message`, it ccould help us solve your problem. As a launcher, there is no need to run `Application.Exit();` after every click. I have made an answer. If you accept it, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: stream also installs a uri protocol handler. So you can just launch `steam://nav/games` (see https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol)

Comment: @NotAgent48 May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @JeremyLakeman and Jiale Xue - MSFT , however thank you for the responses. I will try them out today, and get back to you with if they work. Also I do get an error message telling me it couldn't find the file location or path.

Comment: @NotAgent48  If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT sometimes when I add the file path to the target file it does not work. idk what to do. Also sorry for the late reply!

Comment: @NotAgent48 There may be some problems with your path, you can also try the method from jeremy.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find the path to the target file:

[image]

Below I make a simple demonstration:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\TEST.docx");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer was brought up as an example in a meta thread which you migth want to escalate within your organization. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419331/microsoft-azure-customer-engineers-giving-low-quality-answers

Answer (score 1):

When you run Notepad (Start > Run > Notepad) how does the OS know that `Notepad.exe` lives in the System32 folder? It finds it because the path `C:\Windows\System32` is in the `PATH` environment variable, which tells the OS where to look for executables.

Similarly, put the path where `steam.exe` lives in the Path:

[image: screen shot of System Properties > Advanced > e Environment Variables dialog]